# Is there a way to set a default url parameter for the Route class in Laravel 4?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I'm trying to set up sub-domain based routing in Laravel 4 and I've hit a bit of an annoyance...

My route group looks like this:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => '{company}.domain.com'), function() {
  // ...
});
```

Which seems to work fine, however, I need to specify the `company` parameter for **every** route/url I generate. I.e:

```
{{ HTML::linkRoute('logout', 'Logout', ['company' => Input::get('company')]) }}
```

Is there any way to specify the `company` parameter as *static/global*, so it is automatically added to any links I specify, unless otherwise overwritten/removed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no (I haven't seen any evidence in the router or HTMLBuilder that you can). You could, however, make an HTML macro... Example:

```
HTML::macro('lr', function($link, $title) {
  $company = !empty(Input::get('company')) ? Input::get('company') : "";
  return HTML::linkRoute($link, $title, ['company' => $company]);
});
```

Then call it - instead of `HTML::linkRoute`, use `HTML::lr('logout', 'Logout')`

Just an idea.